# Tool for converting json to openapi specification

Tags: api

I am looking for tool to create openapi specification from json file. For example, I want to convert this:

```
{
    "checked": false,
    "dimensions": {
        "width": 5,
        "height": 10
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.5,
}
```

to

```
  type: object
  title: The root schema
  description: The root schema comprises the entire JSON document.
  default: {}
  example: 
    - checked: false
      dimensions:
        width: 5
        height: 10
      id: 1
      name: A green door
      price: 12.5
      tags:
        - home
        - green
  required:
    - checked
    - dimensions
    - id
    - name
    - price
    - tags
  additionalProperties: true
  properties:
    checked:
      type: boolean
      title: The checked schema
      description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
      default: false
      example:
        - false
    dimensions:
      type: object
      title: The dimensions schema
      description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
      default: {}
      example:
        - width: 5
          height: 10
      required:
        - width
        - height
      additionalProperties: true
      properties:
        width:
          type: integer
          title: The width schema
          description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
          default: 0
          example:
            - 5
        height:
          type: integer
          title: The height schema
          description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
          default: 0
          example:
            - 10
    id:
      type: integer
      title: The id schema
      description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
      default: 0
      example:
        - 1
    name:
      type: string
      title: The name schema
      description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
      default: ''
      example:
        - A green door
    price:
      type: number
      title: The price schema
      description: An explanation about the purpose of this instance.
      default: 0
      example:
        - 12.5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer from the Stack Overflow question [How to generate a Swagger #definition from sample JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277137/how-to-generate-a-swagger-definition-from-sample-json).

And I think [SwagDefGen](https://roger13.github.io/SwagDefGen/) serve your request.

I tried and the generated Swagger file works when I import it in OpenAPI tools (i.e. studio.apicur.io) but it can only contain simple types, not complex types.